# Angular Factory - Altering Returned Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, controller, angular-services

I'm following along on the [Angular JS Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_13) and I was wondering if there is an alternate approach to how I'm modifying it.

Currently, I am returning data with a factory that is defined as such:

```
angular.
    module('core.card').
    factory('Card', ['$resource',
        function($resource){
            return $resource('cards/:cardId.json', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {cardId: 'cards'},
                    isArray: true
                }
            });
        }
    ]);
```

This is all good and working, as `cards.json` has all of the cards available and that's exactly what I want to return.

The method that they're describing, such as dealing with a `RESTful` service, assumes that there are multiple other specific JSON files that could get returned based on the route. I understand how to use that with an actual service, but let's say I wanted to alter the returned JSON data before it gets bound to my module so I don't have a bunch of extra data that I don't need?

Lets say `/cards/foo.json` contains something like this:

```
[{
    "id": "foo",
    "name": "Bar",
    "img": "foobar.png",
    "unnecessaryKey": "remove me"
}]
```

But where would I write a function that only returns:

```
[{
    "id": "foo",
    "name": "Bar",
    "img": "foobar.png"
}]
```

Would I assign it in the same place where the `query` function is, such as:

```
        ...
        return $resource('cards/:cardId.json', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {cardId: 'cards'},
                isArray: true
            },
            alterReturnedData: {
                // doStuffToFormatData
            }
        });
        ...
```

Or would it be best to just modify it in my `Component` as I'm doing now?

```
function alterReturnedData(data){
    // doStuffToFormatData
}
var unmodified = Card.get({cardId:'foo'}, function(){
    self.data = alterReturnedData(unmodified);
});
```

I just feel like it'd be better to return the data from the Service I actually want to the Component Controller instead of having a lot of logic in there to skew it around.

Is my approach OK to run this function in the Controller? 
Or is it best to alter it in the Service, and how would I do so?

Comment: I think that really depends on the given situation. If every single time you are calling the service you know you want to filter out certain data, then it would probably make sense to filter it out there. If that's not the case and you will be filtering different data for different things, then that probably makes sense to be in the corresponding controller. There's of course some gray area between those two. There's no set rule, just do whatever you think makes the most sense for your given situation

Comment: Guess thats why they call Angular an unopinionated platform :P

Comment: Can use `transformResponse` to do what you need. See docs

Comment: Indeed there is a lot of flexibility which comes with its pros and cons. I think in this case though it's relatively easy to see what would make sense: just think of a factory as a way to provide data to your application, and then your application will handle the logic. If your application would always filter out the same data, I wouldn't call that application logic, instead it's just related to what data is provided to the application, so it would go in the factory. I hope that is helpful. (This question also likely belongs on a different one of the exchange sites)